# Sum/Average every group of N elements

Tags: matlab

I have a 720 x 1280 matlab array. I need to sum every 5x5, 10x10, 20x20 and then 40x40 sub array within that and then take the average. This then needs to make 4 new arrays with size (720/5, 1280/5), (720/10, 1280/10),(720/20, 1280/20),(720/40, 1280/40),  How do I do this with for loops?

Comment: you can do this (and it is simpler) without for loops. Do you need the blocks to overlap (a window operation where you move one pixel at a time) or not.?

Comment: What have you tried? I'd suggest trying it yourself on a smaller example, e.g. start with summing all the elements in a 5x5 array, then taking a 20x20 array, summing the 4 5x5 blocks and returning the 4x4 output. This would give you a feel of how to approach the bigger problem

Answer (score 1):

As @bla mentioned, traditionally this would not be done using `for` loops in MATLAB. Regardless, here is an example:

setup

```
data = rand(720, 1280);
windowSize = 5
out = nan(size(data)/windowSize);
```

Here we iterate over each block, where the limits of the block are defined by `((ii-1)*windowSize+1)` and `(ii*windowSize)` (e.g. `1:5`, `6:10`, `11:15`).

```
for ii = 1:size(data, 1)/windowSize
    for jj = 1:size(data, 2)/windowSize
         currentData = data(  ((ii-1)*windowSize+1):(ii*windowSize)  ,...
             ((jj-1)*windowSize+1):(jj*windowSize)  );
         out(ii,jj) = mean(currentData(:));
    end
end
```

Changing the window size can also be automated using a `for` loop, but I will leave this as a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problems, I feel like converting the matrix into a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) of blocks and then using [cellfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) on the blocks makes for a nice and readable code :

```
data = rand(720, 1280);
[sz1,sz2] = size(data);
wSize = 5;

idx1 = wSize*ones(1,sz1/wSize);
idx2 = wSize*ones(1,sz2/wSize);

% Convert input matrix to a cell array of wSize x wSize blocks
C = mat2cell(data,idx1,idx2);

% Apply the "Take the mean of all elements" function to each blocks
out = cellfun(@(X) mean(X(:)),C);
```

Note that `cellfun`, by default, directly concatenates the outputs into an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can do this very easily with [`im2col`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) and then [`mean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) and [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
x = rand(4,6); % data (example)
sz = [2 2]; % block size
result = reshape(mean(im2col(x, sz, 'distinct'), 1), size(x)./sz);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cumsum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) and [diff](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to compute block averages:

```
a = rand(720, 1280);
s(2:720+1, 2:1280+1) = cumsum(cumsum(a, 1), 2);
m5 =  diff(diff(s(1:5:end,  1:5:end),  [], 1), [], 2)/(5*5);
m10 = diff(diff(s(1:10:end, 1:10:end), [], 1), [], 2)/(10*10);
m20 = diff(diff(s(1:20:end, 1:20:end), [], 1), [], 2)/(20*20);
m40 = diff(diff(s(1:40:end, 1:40:end), [], 1), [], 2)/(40*40);
```